# Actionscript - Obtain the name of the current function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe

I want to get the name of a function from inside that function. e.g.:

```
function blah() {
    //I want to get the string "blah" here, from the function's name
}
```

Or at least the Function object?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [arguments.callee](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/arguments.html#callee) to get a reference to the current function.

I you want to get the function name, it is a bit trickier: All functions are treated as method closures (pieces of code which can be passed around as an argument), so they do not own a reference to an enclosing class type, nor do they have a "current name".

However, if (and *only* if) the method is public, and you want to get the method name from the class declaration of an instance object containing the method, you can use [describeType](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29):

```
public function someFunction() : void {
    var callee:Function = arguments.callee;
    trace (getFunctionName(callee, this)); // ==> someFunction
}

private function someOtherFunction() : void {
    var callee:Function = arguments.callee;
    trace (getFunctionName(callee, this)); // ==> not found
}

private function getFunctionName (callee:Function, parent:Object):String {
    for each ( var m:XML in describeType(parent)..method) {
        if ( parent[m.@name] == callee) return m.@name;
    }
    return "not found";
}
```

Note that this would not work when you call `someFunction()` from a constructor, because the object is not fully instantiated - `describeType(this)` in a constructor would cause a compilation error.

Comment: quick note: if you want to be able to use this from another class, you have to replace `this[m.@name]` with `parent[m.@name]`

Comment: That was actually a bug. Thanks for bringing it to my attention, @kriswelsh

Answer (score 5):

I just did it with a stack trace, which is what the Flash Player debugger shows when an unhandled error is thrown.  Here's my implementation:

```
function blah()
{
    var e:Error = new Error();
    var s:String = e.getStackTrace();
    var functionName:String = s.slice(s.indexOf('/')+1, s.indexOf('('));
    trace(functionName); //blah
}
```

You'll probably need to make the parsing of the string a bit fancier, if you want to make this a separate function.  But the function name is definitely in the stack trace.

**Edit: Important Caveat**

The [AS3 Lang Ref](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html) says that the getStackTrace method only works in the Debugger versions of Flash Player/AIR, and will return `null` otherwise.  So this is definitely not a deployable solution.  Sorry.

Comment: As of version 11.5 and later it's available in non-debugger versions. Quote, `For Flash Player 11.4 and earlier and AIR 3.4 and earlier, stack traces are only available when code is running in the debugger version of Flash Player or the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL). In non-debugger versions of those runtimes, calling this method returns null.` - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html

Answer (score 2):

You probably wont be able to get the name of a function, because they don't *really* have a "name" as such. Just like your variables don't have names. They are just pointers to an object.

Getting the name doesn't make sense, partly due to the following example:

```
function foo():void 
{
    //get function name.
}
var bar:Function = foo;
bar();
```

A function is just like any other object/variable. What "name" would this function find? "foo"? or "bar"? Both foo and bar are referencing the same variable of type [Function](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Function.html).

A better way to handle this would be to pass something in to the function as an argument:

```
function foo(myName:String):void 
{
    trace(myName);
}
```

You can however, get a reference to the current function using the [arguments.callee](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/arguments.html#callee) :)

Comment: I find what you're saying really hard to believe.  Even when I compile a release version Flex app with trace statements suppressed and no source view, if an unhandled error is thrown, Flash Player will provide me a sequence of methods _by name_, including the associated class and it's respective package.  That suggests to me that function _name_ info is definitely encoded into the swf, and hence should be accessible somehow.

Comment: ...the difference being that the stack is traced "from the outside", as an introspective operation, which allows for the entire class and object hierarchy of the program to be known, while this is impossible from within a function body.  You could always have some kind of "custom stack" that keeps track of your object an method calls, if you want to have similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

To pull this off in Actionscript 2, which I had to do recently with some legacy code

```
function getFunctionName(func:Function):String
{
  for(var prop in this)
  {
    if(this[prop] == func)
    {
      return prop;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And use it something like this

```
trace(getFunctionName(arguments.callee));
```

Answer (score 0):

when i needed IDs for functions for my event system implementation i didn't find a way to access a `name` of a non-anonymous function passed as an argument so i had to write a wrapper that stored nothing except the `Function` and its `ID`