# Does Actionscript have something like magic constants?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Yes, I am new to Actionscript/Flex/Flash, but I'd really like to call something like C/C++/PHP/etc magic constants like:

```
__FUNCTION__
__LINE__
__FILE__
```

Is there an equivalent in Actionscript 3.0? When compiling, I get the error:

```
Error: Access of undefined property __FUNCTION__.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: I'd like to identify what function, line and file are currently executing.

Comment: I think that this question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149073/stacktrace-in-flash-actionscript-3-0

Comment: @randy Jacob's answe covers a big chunk. I'd also recommend looking into the debugger if you haven't already (comes with the Adobe products, but I'm not sure which poison you chose).

Comment: @Jacob - thanks, I will deal with a full stacktrace, if that's as close as I can get.

Comment: @Jackson - I was hoping for built-ins. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special object named [arguments](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html) accessible in each function. It can be used to get arguments (as the name already implies):

```
arguments[0] // first argument
```

It can also be used to get you a reference to the called function:

```
arguments.callee
```

In earlier Actionscript versions there it also had a `caller` property, but not in AS3 any more.

There is a way to get the name of a function using the callee property: [Actionscript - Obtain the name of the current function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4731935/897024)

Comment: This may be as close as it gets for AS3. +1

Comment: Side note: `arguments[0]` will online work **inside** a function block that has at least one parameter. Just some clarification for those that are really really new. +1 for being more enlightened than me.